# How to make autoconf use "install" instead of "mkdir -p"?

Tags: chmod, umask, mkdir, automake, autoconf

When I run `sudo make install` on a compiled package from the GNU archive, it uses `mkdir -p` to create the destination directories.

I'd prefer it to use `mkdir -p -m 0755` or `install -d -m 0755` instead in order to ensure the destination directory has proper permissions for everyone under all circumstances, not just when the umask for root is 0022 (which isn't true for me).

The package is using autoconf/automake and it looks like the behaviour is controlled by an M4 macro called `AC_PROG_MKDIR_P`.

At the moment I can run `sudo chmod 0755` on the directories I know have wrong permissions. But this isn't clearly the right option.

I'd avoid to study the whole documentation in order to accomplish "just that".

Any hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The macro `AC_PROG_MKDIR_P` is a feature test macro. It expands to shell code that tests for the best `mkdir -p`-capable command available. It uses `MKDIR_P` and `ac_cv_path_mkdir` (a "cache variable") to figure out what command to use.

You may set the value of `MKDIR_P` to the command that you want to use for creating directories. The command that you use must be able to create not only a single directory but also the parent directories if these are not already existing (just like `mkdir -p` does).

Normal:

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
...
```

With `MKDIR_P` set:

```
$ ./configure MKDIR_P='install -d -m 0755'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... install -d -m 0755
checking for gawk... gawk
...
```

According to [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Particular-Programs.html), one should be able to make this "permanent" by setting the cache variable `ac_cv_path_mkdir` to the wanted command.  This variable can be set directly in the `configure` script (ugly) or by modifying the created `config.cache` file after running `configure` with the `-C` option once.  *However*, I've found that `configure` adds a `-p` option to the value of this command which may not be wanted (the meaning of this option is different between `mkdir` and `install`).

If you're happy with re-generating the `configure` script from its `configure.ac` source, you may set `MKDIR_P` to a value just after the call to `AC_INIT`.  Then run `autoconf` (or `autoreconf`) to recreate `configure`.

The most flexible way would be to set the `MKDIR_P` environment variable in the current shell session with `export MKDIR_P='install -d'` (or whatever you need).  This would not require modifying any files, but would affect all `configure` scripts that you run in that shell session.

Comment: It works, indeed. Is there a way to make this choice "permanent" within the ./configure script?

Comment: @Enzo See my updated answer.

Comment: I think the proper way is the one you hint with "If you're happy with re-generating the configure script...". But it's not clear to me whether MKDIR_P="mkdir -m 0755" is enough.

Comment: @Enzo Is enough, for what? (or who?) (or when?)

Comment: I just added that line (MKDIR_P="mkdir -m 0755") and did the who run. IT WORKS. THANKS.

Comment: @Enzo Good! You may want to add `-p` to that though. You will want it to create missing intermediate directories too.